# ember.js - todos example

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to work through this tutorial to learn ember - http://www.tuanleaded.com/blog/2012/04/getting-started-with-ember-js-the-missing-to-dos-manual/  I have the following html and javascript but when I run it and enter a todo, followed by the enter key it only adds a checkbox to the list instead of putting a label next to the checkbox with the title of the todo.  I've noticed that the todo project that comes with ember.js in the examples does the same thing and I don't know why.

Here's the html.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="ie6"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie7"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=2">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{view Todos.CreateToDoView id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?"}}

    {{#collection contentBinding="Todos.todosController" tagName="ul" itemClassBinding="content.isDone"}}
        {{view Em.Checkbox titleBinding="content.title" valueBinding="content.isDone"}}
    {{/collection}}
  </script>

  <!-- The missing protocol means that it will match the current protocol, either http or https. If running locally, we use the local jQuery. -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.pre.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my app.js file...

```
/*models*/

var Todos = Em.Application.create();

Todos.Todo = Em.Object.extend({
    title: null,
    isDone: false
});


/*controller*/

Todos.todosController = Em.ArrayProxy.create({
    content:[],

    createTodo: function(title){
        var todo = Todos.Todo.create({ title: title });
        this.pushObject(todo);  
    }
});

/*views*/

Todos.CreateToDoView = Em.TextField.extend({
    insertNewline : function(){
        var value = this.get("value");

        if (value){
            Todos.todosController.createTodo(value);
            this.set("value","");   
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{#collection contentBinding="Todos.todosController" tagName="ul" itemClassBinding="content.isDone"}}
     {{view Em.Checkbox titleBinding="content.title" valueBinding="content.isDone"}}
{{/collection}}
```

All you are doing here is displaying a checkbox. Ember.Checkbox has no concept of title or a titleBinding. If you just add `{{view.content.title}}` next to that checkbox you'll see the title show next to it.

See Ember.Checkbox for what it supports/does: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/checkbox.js

**UPDATE:**

I've changed your fiddle to be working. Lots of little changes, let me know if you have any questions: http://jsfiddle.net/WKn3P/2/

Comment: Okay, I've updated my code to this but it still does not display what I enter.  {{view Em.Checkbox titleBinding="content.title" valueBinding="content.isDone"}} {{content.title}}

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle. that way we can edit it together and see what is wrong.

Comment: Okay, but now I can't even get it to load.  I've referenced all the same scripts so I'm not sure what's going on.  Here's the link - http://jsfiddle.net/WKn3P/

Comment: Great, thanks so much for the help.  I'm looking forward to digging into this and hopefully it'll make sense.